# AJAX posting additional data using jQuery sortable (not form)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got a page that's using the jQuery UI sortable plugin to update the sort orders of items using AJAX. That all works well but I'd like to be able to add to that the ability to delete items using checkboxes. I have no problem passing along additional static information to the post but I'm not sure how to send a querystring of dynamically created and selected items.

Here's my jQuery:

```
var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
  ui.children().each(function() {
    $(this).width($(this).width());
  });
  return ui;
};
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sortable tbody").sortable({ 
    helper: fixHelper,
    opacity: 0.6, 
    update: function(){
      $('#savemessage').html('<p>Click <em>Remove/Reorder</em> to save</p>');

      }
  });
  $('#button').click(function(event){
    var order = $("#sortable tbody").sortable("serialize");
    order += "&crudtype=update_favorites";
    $('#savemessage').html('<p>Saving changes...</p>');
    $.post("/crud",order,function(theResponse){
        $('#savemessage').html(theResponse);
      });
  });
});
```

Here's my PHP which renders the table rows and data:

```
foreach ($favorites as $key => $favorite) {
  print '<tr class="' . zebra($key) . '" id="field_' . $favorite['fid'] . '">
    <td class="handle"><a href="#">' . $favorite['name'] . '</a></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="fid[]" id="fid" value="' . $favorite['fid'] . '" class="box check-child"></td>
    </tr>';
}
print '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove/Reorder Selected Favorites" class="form-submit-table" id="button">';
```

Ultimately I'd like to be able to gather the values of fid[] that were checked and then (presumably) add them to the JS *order* variable which gets passed to my AJAX processing page, but I'm at a loss as to how to do that as I'm a bit of a jQuery novice.

I've seen a few posts on how to get information from a form but in this case, since I'm using the Sortable plugin, I'm not actually using a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the form name is .. but

```
var str = $("form[name=yourForm").serialize();
```

should do it.

In other words

```
<form name="yourForm">

<?php /* your code */ ?>

</form>
```

and

```
var formString = $("form[name=yourForm").serialize();

$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    data : formString,
    success : function(response){
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't actually have a form in place since I'm using the Sortable plugin but if I add one, would that command serialize *all* form fields?  If so, is there a way to just collect the data from the checkbox array (fid[], in this case?)

Comment: It would serialize all form fields .. I would try to wrap the form element around just the checkboxes - it should work ok for you:-)

Comment: Ok -- I added the form and the following code after naming it: order += $("form[name=favorites").serialize(); But I'm getting a syntax error.  Something to do with the quotes?  I'm not familiar with that syntax. EDIT: Found it.  Should be form[name=favorites].  Thanks so much!